# Limit of a Power sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $P_n=a^{P_{n-1}}-1$ for all $n=2,3,\ldots $ and let $P_1=a^x-1$ where $a $ is a positive real number, then evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac {P_n}{x} $$ How do I start on this one?

Comment: I think $P_n'(0)={log(a)}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Observe that by induction we have $P_n(0)=0$ for all $n$. Thus the limit is actually 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{P_n(x)-P_n(0)}{x}=P_n'(0).$$

Comment: What does (0) mean?

Comment: How do I simplify it after that.?

Comment: @mathgeek $P_n(0)$ means evaluate the function $P_n$ at the point $x=0$. Just like $\sin(0)=0$. Try differentiating the recursion formula and plugging in $x=0$.